# Is SQLite "Insert or Replace" slower than just "Insert"?

Tags: sqlite, replace, insert

I am copying millions of rows to a table in another database. I am doing a few things with the data in-between and have duplicates on a certain column that is used as a key in the destination table. Ignoring all the other solutions to fix this, I am testing out using "Insert or Replace" and so far processing is going smooth, but I am not sure whether this is faster than a normal "Insert" (given a case where there are no PK duplicates)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OR REPLACE clause works only if there is some UNIQUE (or PRIMARY KEY) constraint that could be violated.

This means that the database *always* has to check whether there is a duplicate, the only difference is what happens when a duplicate is found: report an error, or delete the old row.